# Abstract List<Person>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, abstract-class

*Update: My classes are more complex than this, I just am stuck on the ArrayList line*

I have the following classes:

```
class CatList {

    List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();

}
```

and

```
class DogList {

    List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();

}
```

Where Cat and dog are both data classes.

but I want to create an abstract class:

```
abstract class AnimalList {

    List<???> animals;

    AnimalList(Class animal) {

        animals = new ArrayList<???>();

    }
}
```

so that I can inherit my classes

```
AnimalList CatList = new AnimalList(Cat);
AnimalList DogList = new AnimalList(Dog);
AnimalList CowList = new AnimalList(Cow);
```

Hopefully that makes more sense. My question is therefore What are the ??? bits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a type parameter might solve your problem - using the same class for different types - without inheritance:

```
public class AnimalList<T> {
  private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

  public void add(T animal) {
    list.add(animal);
  }
  // more methods
}
```

Now you can parametize instances for persons and animals:

```
AnimalList<Cat> catList = new AnimalList<Cat>();
catList.add(new Cat());
AnimalList<Dog> dogList = new AnimalList<Dog>();
dogList.add(new Dog());
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas_D I haven't explained this very well. The ArrayList code is just part of what I am trying to achieve, I'm just unsure of the syntax in the ???

Comment: Ah I see now. I have to use the <T> thingy :-) and I don't need the constructor, i.e.     public class AnimalList<T> {
        List<T> animals = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

Answer (score 1):

My advice is, to create a base class for Dog and Cat, let's say Animal. This way you spare yourself some time, because you don't have to write the same methods and members in both classes, and it works like this:

```
public (abstract) class Animal
{
    members and functions, that both Cats, and Dogs have... 
}
```

then inherit from Animal like this:

```
public class Cat extends Animal
{
    ...
}
```

From now on you can create an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
animals.add(new Cat());
animals.add(new Dog());
```

If you want to create an AnimalList anyway, then your best option is Andreas's solution, generics are meant for these kind of situation.

IF you know, how inheritance works, and you already considered building your application like this, then sorry for my post!

Answer (score 1):

As was said, you might want to define a base class Animal for Cat and Dog and then:

```
class AnimalList<T extends Animal> {

    private List<T> animals;

    protected AnimalList() {
       animals = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
```

If you need to pass the Class you might wand to define yje constructor as:

```
AnimalList(Class<T> type) { … }
```

If you need to handle some AnimalList for some unknown Animal type you might use:

```
private AnimalList<? extends Animal> list;
```